# Unable to link a work item to the test results based on the document

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

When I was following this document [Publish Test Results task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=junit%2Cyaml#result-formats-mapping)
I didn't find any field to link a work item to a test case. Do I need to call an api to do this? Or is there any field that isn't in the document?

Thanks!
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

We could add the work item in the test run result summary page.

In the build summary page->click the tab test->select the test result, we could see the `run id` and `resultId` in the URL

[image]

Open **Test Plans**->click the tab **Runs**->select the test run and open it->click the tab **Test results** and open it->we could see the button **Bug**->click it, then we could select create new bug or add existing bug. You could check the pic below.

[image]

**Update1**

We could do this via [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to add work item.

Sample:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=6.0
```

Request Body:

```
[
  {
    "id": {Result ID},
    "state": "Completed",
    "comment": "{Comment}",
    "associatedBugs": [
      {
        "id": {Bug ID}
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then we could check it in the UI or this [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Sample:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results/{testCaseResultId}?detailsToInclude=workItems&api-version=6.0-preview
```

Note: We could get test run ID in the task publish test result log. We could add power shell task and enter the script to add the work item in the pipeline.

Power shell script sample:

```
$connectionToken="{PAT}"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
$Url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=6.0"  
$Body = @"
[
  {
    "id": {Result ID},
    "state": "Completed",
    "comment": "{Comment}",
    "associatedBugs": [
      {
        "id": {Bug ID}
      }
    ]
  }
]
"@


$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Body $Body -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method PATCH
```

Comment: Thanks Vito, instead of manually creating/linking a new bug, is that possible to link an existing work item(i.e. task, test case, not a bug) programmatically? For example, in testResult.xml, can we add an attribute someting like workItemId to a testcase? Or I have already use azure-devops-node-api to create a new test run and update the results, how could I publish the new test run? like in the Publish Test Results agent job, I publish the test result by giving a test run id? Or do you know how I could get a test result xml file from the test run? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @JasonHao, We could do this via REST API, I have updated the answer, you could check the update1 and kindly share the result here.

Comment: Hi @JasonHao, Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if you have any questions. If the answer could help, you may consider accepting it.